# Lovasz extension subgradient for non-submodular functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, discrete-optimization

Let $f(S) : \{0,1\}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a set function and let $F(z): [0,1]^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be its Lovasz extension.

If the set function $f(S)$ is submodular, then a subgradient of the Lovasz extension $F(z)$ can be computed relatively quickly (e.g. page 21 of [https://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/submodular_fbach_eth_april_2016.pdf](https://www.di.ens.fr/%7Efbach/submodular_fbach_eth_april_2016.pdf)).

I am wondering: are there any easy-to-compute formulas for a subgradient of the Lovasz extension $F(z)$ if the set function $f(S)$ is *not* submodular?

Thanks!

Comment: If $f(S)$ is not submodular then $F(z)$ is not convex.  Nonconvex functions don't have subgradients.

Comment: Darn, that's disappointing. Oh well, thank you @BrianBorchers !